# What is the name and ID of this part and what is it used for?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, bricklink

Attached is a picture of the clone part, what is its name and ID, and what is it used for?

I tried looking for it on [rebrickable.com](https://rebrickable.com/parts/) or [bricklink.com](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P) but couldn't find it anywhere.

The part is orange, I saw it in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F1M6PJJ) clone set.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The linked set is a Lego clone brand, however all the parts (including the subject of this question) do indeed exist as Lego parts too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image you received is a clone part

but this is part # 96874

[Brick and Axle Separator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=96874&idColor=4#T=C&C=4)[image]

it is used to separate bricks and other parts

[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LZmGjKqcr8&t=1s) could be helpful